# Error in update arraylist in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am sending the arraylist from android to php. i want replace old menunames as new menunames. in my table contains two columns 1.menuimage 2.menuname.. i want to update only new menunames

my table structure

```
                  test(table name)
           menucode     menuimage   menuname
             1            image       p
             2              "         q
             3              "          r
             4              "          s
             5              "           t
```

i want update only menuname according to the menucode ... i am passing menucode[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]...

```
<?php

   $old_menu_code = explode(",", str_replace(array("[","]"), "", $_POST['menucode']));
   $new_menu_names = explode(",", str_replace(array("[","]"), "", $_POST['editmainmenu']));
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
  mysql_select_db("test");
  foreach ($old_menu_names as $key => $old_name) {
  $new_name = mysql_real_escape_string($new_menu_names[$key]);
  $old_code = mysql_real_escape_string($old_menu_code[$key]);

  mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menucode= '$old_code'") or die('Error' . mysql_error());
echo "Updated";
   }
  ?>
```

the above code  test is database contains test table.in test table contains two columns one menuimage and menuname . in menuimage contains 7 images and menuname contains 7 menunmaes. i want only update menuinames. but above code update only first row menunames column. remaining rows are not updated..please what mistake i have been done

Comment: add sample value of what you are expecting form `$_POST['menuname']` and `$_POST['editmainmenu']` .. i don't want to assume

Comment: [p,q,r,s,t,u] this old arraylist, [a,b,c,d,e,f] this new menunames arraylist

Comment: @Vinoth:Did u  send arrays in arraylist.Actually i dont know to get this array list in php when send from android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `str_replace` & `explode` to achieve what you want ..

**Spiting Data**

```
$old_menu_names = "[p,q,r,s,t,u]" ; // or $old_menu_names = $_POST['menuname'] ;
$new_menu_names = "[a,b,c,d,e,f]" ; // or $new_menu_names = $_POST['editmainmenu'] ;

$old_menu_names = explode(",", str_replace(array("[","]"), "", $old_menu_names));
$new_menu_names = explode(",", str_replace(array("[","]"), "", $new_menu_names));
```

**SQL ERROR**

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menuname = '$old_name'")
```

What statement would not work because you are trying to update a filed `menuname` that you are using in where condition `WHERE menuname =`

I would recommend you change it to something like `memuid` if it exist in your table or get the `ID` first and use it to update it .

**EDIT 1**

Updated Code

```
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","test");
$sql = "SELECT menucode FROM test where menuname = '%s' ";

foreach ($old_menu_names as $key => $old_name) {
    $new_name = mysql_real_escape_string($new_menu_names[$key]);
    $old_code = mysql_real_escape_string($old_menu_names[$key]);
    $result = $mysql->query(sprintf($sql,$old_code))->fetch_assoc();

    if(!empty($result['menucode']))
    {
        $mysql->query(sprintf("UPDATE `test` SET `menuname` = '%s' WHERE menucode= '%d'",$new_name,$result['menucode']));
        echo "Updated " , $mysql->affected_rows .  PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Missing menucode for $old_code " , PHP_EOL;
    }
 }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: how can assign my postvalues through url to old menunames and newmenunames please tell me

Comment: i try ur code it replaces p as a only.. remaining are not updated

Comment: to assign post value  ... you replace `"[p,q,r,s,t,u]"` with `$_POST['menuname']` ...  on the insert issue i know why its not working ... i would update my answer now ...

Comment: i don't know . now i am trying with id. wait for a moment

Comment: now i can add menucode column in database i can pass url as menucode[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] i want update newmenunames according to the menucode .. please tell me how can i do

Comment: give me your table structure and sample data .. then i can write a new script for you

Comment: see updated code and tell me if that is what you want .. note am using `mysqli` improved version for `mysql`